# Is it possible to know the newly added symbol in a HashSet?

Tags: java

I have this piece of code inside my application which runs continuously .

When ever  a symbol is added , this below Thread gets fired up and executes two different tasks ( currently the task is represented as sys out for simplicity )

For the first time everything runs fine , but from the second time , the task is being repeated for all the symbols present inside the allSymbolsSet .

The issue i am facing here is that i want to run the task only for the new symbol added . (For example if the allSymbolsSet consists of 3 symbols initially and when a new symbol is added to it , it runs that task for all the 4 symbols , whereas i want it to execute it only for the newly added symbol )

This is my code

```
package com;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;

public class TaskerThread extends Thread {
    private PriorityBlockingQueue<String> priorityBlocking = new PriorityBlockingQueue<String>();
    private Set<String> allSymbolsSet = new HashSet<String>();

    public void addSymbols(String str) {
        if (str != null) {
            priorityBlocking.add(str);
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                boolean added = false;
                while (priorityBlocking.peek() != null) {
                    added = true;
                    String symbol = priorityBlocking.poll();
                    allSymbolsSet.add(symbol);
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Symbol From priorityBlocking"+ "  " + symbol);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                Iterator<String> ite = allSymbolsSet.iterator();
                if (added) {
                    while (ite.hasNext()) {
                        String symbol = ite.next();
                        if (symbol != null && symbol.trim().length() > 0) {
                            try {
                                System.out.println("Symbol From allSymbolsSet"+ "   " + symbol);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            TaskerThread qT = new TaskerThread();
            qT.start();
            qT.addSymbols("SymbolTest");
        Thread.sleep(110);
        qT.addSymbols("Symbo2222222");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HashSet is not thread safe and neither are its iterators.

Comment: @bsd - this code uses HashSet within a single thread, so there aren't any threading issues...

Answer (score 6):

`add()` method returns false if the Object being added was ignored because it was already present

Comment: agree but assume that if a new symbol is added , in that case the second task will run for the newly added as well as for all the symbols in the allSymbolsSet .

Comment: I have modified the main method , please run this for your reference .

Comment: @Kiran - move the added block into the loop and run it on the added symbol.

Comment: @jtahlborn yes thats waht my requirement is

Comment: @Kiran - okay, so what is your question?

Comment: @jtahlborn the second task (sys out ) is running for all the symbols present inside the HasHset as well as for the new symbol also .

Comment: @Kiran - as i wrote above "move the added block into the loop and run it on the added symbol"

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to have two hashsets - set1, holding all symbols, set2 containing newly added symbols. Add new symbols to set2, in your thread's run, when the execution is complete, add new symbol to set1 and remove it from set2. How about that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course it runs for all elements in the set, you are iterating over them!

```
package com;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;

public class TaskerThread extends Thread {
    private final PriorityBlockingQueue<String> priorityBlocking = new PriorityBlockingQueue<String>();
    private final Set<String> allSymbolsSet = new Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<String>());

    public void addSymbols(String str) {
        if (str != null) {
            priorityBlocking.add(str);
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    final String symbol = priorityBlocking.take();
                    if (allSymbolsSet.add(symbol)) {
                        doSomething(symbol); // do whatever you want with the symbol
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            TaskerThread qT = new TaskerThread();
            qT.start();
            qT.addSymbols("SymbolTest");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This should do what you were looking for. Take better care of possible exceptions, namely InterruptedException.